# Redmine watchers can not see issues which are not assigned to them

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

My customers do have a role in which I've defined "can view issues assigned or created by the user"

Now when I create an issue, I need to add a customer sometimes as a watcher. But in this case, the watcher user can not view this issue because he in not the creator nor the asignee of the issue.

Is there a way in which I don't have to give permission to view all issues but also can view some issues as watchers? Plugins recommendations are also appreciated.

Comment: try this plugin https://github.com/twinslash/redmine_tracker_accessible (see chapter "Special access")